# Implement a Playlist Queuing System for a Song Request App in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So the purpose of this app is to allow customers at a venue to requests songs to be played to the host/dj. The host take requests of the songs and plays it at his will. The host also is allowed to change the position of the songs that is to be played.

When a user requests a song it automatically adds it to the bottom of the playlist queue, the 'position' field is updated by simply taking the count of the playlist queue.

But, the host is allowed to change the position, if he/she decides to push a track up from position 5 to 2. The songs in between should also increment their position accordingly.

A simple, solution to this is to x+1 on all the songs in between the old and new position. But this would create a lot of write operations on the db, it is very much possible that a song is pushed from no.100 to no.2, which would in return lead to 98 write operations on the database.

Would there be any better solution out of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shouldn't think of Songs table order as a way in which you will serve songs on playlist. It would be good idea if you could query songs in some structured way but as you said you will be moving songs around playlist.

I would think of implementing some kind of `Playlist` model which can hold array of all songs added by users (each new song gets pushed to the end of array).

At the same time DJ have access to this array and can move song to specific position in array. At most it will be one operation on db per songs order change because you would only be changing array with references to songs, not songs themselves.